# working with a database record without saving it in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, session-variables

I am developing an application using ruby on Rails that is going to be used to train learners in high fidelity simulations in which they need to record notes in an web based electronic record-keeping system.

The idea is to be able to allow users to retrieve a simulated record from the database, interact with it by adding child records that represent procedure notes, messages to other people and the like, and at the end of the session display the changes and additions that were made. After all of that the "template" record will need to be able to be reset to its original state, returning to the state it was in before the user worked with it.

Multiple users will use the same "template" record in different simulation rooms, so changes made by one user should not affect the data available to other users.

I have already developed much of the application using generated scaffolding that I have modified to produce the basic functionality of the record system.

Now I need to figure out the "simulation mode" functionality which allows a user to "tear off" a copy of a record that will be thrown away after changes are made at the end of a session.

Has anyone developed a rails application that has similar requirements to those I listed above?

I am thinking I will need to store copies of the patient and its child objects in session variables. Are there any examples available to that show how to store copies of objects in session variables and modify and add to those objects using forms? Any help and advice would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is version management.  There are a number of gems to do this, I suggest looking at:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail

...and see if the kind of functionality can be addressed with paper trail.  If not, checkout:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Versioning

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited

very cool gem, you simply store the audit state in session to which you then roll back.